# Fazer autenticação com Identity e/ou Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-azure, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

Hoje a aplicação do cliente faz autenticação utilizando Identity (.net core 3.1), no entanto estou tentando fazer autenticação também por Azure AD, adicionando um botão extra na página de login aonde o usuário pode fazer o login no AD. O que acontece é que todo o processo é feito normalmente, mas ao redirecionar para a aplicação, ou seja, efetivar o login e redirecionar para o dashboard da aplicação, o redirecionameto acaba não funcionando, ou seja, volta para a página inicial onde há o form de login e senha tradicional e o botão que criar para o login no AD.

Consegui fazer uma implementação parecida com esta (sem o AddOpenIdConnect) para login junto ao Google e obtive sucesso. Estou tendo dificuldade agora para implementar o Azure AD.
Segui este tutorial para este caso do Google. O cliente pede algo parecido com isso: https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-login-with-google/

Startup.cs

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("AzureAD", options =>
        {
            //  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
            options.ClientId = "ClientId ";
            options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret ";
            options.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
            options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0/";
            options.ResponseType = "id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.UsePkce = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                NameClaimType = "email",
            };
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            options.Prompt = "login";
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(o =>
        {
        o.ApplicationCookie.PostConfigure(option =>
        {
            option.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
            option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45);
            option.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            option.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOffAsync";
        });
        });

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            //double check your version here
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0/";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

        });
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("login-ad")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult LoginAD(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) { returnUrl = "/"; }
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl },
                AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                );
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("signin-oidc")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult SigninOidc(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            //não implementado
            return null;
        }
    }
```

_loginPartial

```
 <a href="/login-ad" class="btn btn-complete btn-Login m-t-10">
        UTILIZAR O LOGIN DA EMPRESA
    </a>
```